# Extracting entries in tab delimited text file outside the target sites

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am new to linux. I have two tab delimited text files

File_A

```
aaa    90      111    
aaa    95      110
aaa    102     115
aaa    105     118
aaa    107     119
aaa    117     130
```

and file_B

```
aaa 100   120
```

Now I would like to retain all the entries in file_A which outside the ranges of file_B like follows

```
aaa    90      111    
aaa    95      110
aaa    117     130
```

Kindly guide me.

Comment: this is relatively straightforward, have you tried anything? guide you or write codes for you? just load fileB, save the range in two var, then load each line of fileA, compare the $2 and $3, if  they were out of the range, print. I guess this is homework.

Comment: Is the first field (`aaa`) **always** just one common value across both files? Is `file_B` always just 1 line? If the answer is `no` to either question then please [edit] your question to use sample input/output that includes those cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This awk should work:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{low[$1]=$2; high[$1]=$3; next}
     $1 in low && ($2 <= low[$1] || $3 >= high[$1])' file2 file1

aaa    90      111
aaa    95      110
aaa    117     130
```

Comment: That **might** actually be overkill since there seems to be only one `$1` value across all files.

Comment: Yes I tried to make it generic so that it can work with different values in column 1 in both files.

Comment: Yup, I understood that. Just not sure the OP has that case.